# python group by sum like this how to do

Tags: python, group-by

description:
     my data from mongodb the item like this:

```
     { "_id" : "5620150715", "timeStamp" : NumberLong("1436889600000"), "userId" : 56, "WorldAmounts" : [ { "count" : NumberLong(10), "Address" : "aaa" }, { "count" : NumberLong(20), "Address" : "bbb" } ], "Amounts" : [ { "count" : NumberLong(10), "ipAddress" : "aaa" }, { "count" : NumberLong(20), "Address" : "bbb" } ], "date" : "20150715", "localAmounts" : [ ] }
```

Question:
      how to group by the all item  and the key is "`userId`" and the "`Address`" in `WorldAmounts`?

the test data like this:

```
[{'userId':1, 'localA': [{'address':'A','count':7},{'address':'B', 'count':10}], 'localB': [{'address':'X','count':5}], 'localALL':[{'address':'A','count':7},{'address':'B', 'count':10},{'address':'X','count':5}]},{'userId':2, 'localA': [{'address':'A','count':7},{'address':'B', 'count':10}], 'localB': [{'address':'X','count':5}], 'localALL':[{'address':'A','count':7},{'address':'B', 'count':10},{'address':'X','count':5}]},{'userId':1, 'localA': [{'address':'C','count':7}], 'localB': [{'address':'X','count':5}], 'localALL':[{'address':'A','count':7},{'address':'B', 'count':10},{'address':'X','count':5}]}]
```

the result  like is:
    IF THE '`userId`' is diff not use groupby ,the `localALL` is `LocalA + LocalB`, IF the same '`address`' value ,sum of the '`count`'  else append the local

```
[{'userId':1, 'localA': [{'address':'C','count':7},{'address':'A','count':7},{'address':'B', 'count':10}], 'localB': [{'address':'X','count':10}], 'localALL':[{'address':'A','count':7},{'address':'B', 'count':10},{'address':'X','count':10}]},
{'userId':2, 'localA': [{'address':'A','count':7},{'address':'B', 'count':10}], 'localB': [{'address':'X','count':5}], 'localALL':[{'address':'A','count':7},{'address':'B', 'count':10},{'address':'X','count':5}]}
]
```

thx  alfasin's advice the best simple example  like this:

input :
[{'abs':1 , 'lad': [{'count':2, 'desc':'A'},{'count':3,'desc':4}]},
{'abs':1 , 'lad': [{'count':3, 'desc':'A'},{'count':1,'desc':5}]}]

output:

[{'abs': 1, 'lst': [{'count': 5, 'desc': 3}, {'count': 3, 'desc': 4}，{'count': 1, 'desc': 5}]}]

Comment: TMI, try to construct a *simple* example which will include input + requested output

Comment: i think the best simple example like this : input:       [{'abs':1 , 'lad': [{'count':2, 'desc':'A'},{'count':3,'desc':4}]},
{'abs':1 , 'lad': [{'count':3, 'desc':'A'},{'count':1,'desc':5}]}]  and output:    [{'abs': 1, 'lst': [{'count': 5, 'desc': 3}, {'count': 3, 'desc': 4}，{'count': 1, 'desc': 5}]}]

Comment: `collections.defaultdict(list)` might be helpful here. Run your input  data structure through a for loop to populate your output data structure

Comment: but the each item  is in mongodb   i can get a cursor  and use iter get the data one by one